# After iOS 5 update, files in my document directory are gone? Is iOS changing the documents directory?

Tags: ios, filesystems, ios5, nsdocumentdirectory

I have a little problem with my app when updating to iOS5.
In my documents directory I have a sqlite file and PDF documents.
The sqlite file contains the url's of the PDF documents.

When I start my app, I can see the list of documents, which is saved in the sqlite file.
But when I want to open a pdf, the document is not found.

So I think iOS changes the document directory addresses.
Is that possible?

I save the addresses of my pdf's like that:

```
NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, 
                                                                       NSUserDomainMask,
                                                                       YES);
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@",[pathArr objectAtIndex:0],title,versionString];
```

Comment: This same thing happens to me. The file is still there but the app cannot find it. If it creates a new one with the same name, it can find it and open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to answer your question without mor information. The fact that you are able to read the sqlite file which you say is in the Documents folder indicates that your program can at least find that file.

You can look and see what exactly is in the Documents folder by setting the
  *Application Supports iTunes file sharing*
attribute in the Application's info.plist file.  You can then view the Application's Documents folder and add/remove files in iTunes.

You can also look in the

```
~Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<IOSVERSION>/Applications/<UUID>/Documents
```

directory if you are running the simulator.

You will at least know what the actual contents of the Documents directory are...

Comment: Well the files are there. But I think the problem is, that I hardcode the file path of the pdf and save it to the sqlite file. I think NSDocumentDirectory returns something different in iOS5 than in iOS4. Also how can I simulate a version update? Because when I do a fresh install in iOS5, it is working fine.

Comment: I would say that you have no choice other than looking at the path stored in the sqlite db and trim it (if necessary) and append it to the current path returned by NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains. Then you don't care about version updates.

Comment: @John, is the NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains folder returns <Application_Home>/Library/Cache/ instead of <Application_Home>/Documents in iOS5.0? I read that for iOS 5 you need to store all your downloaded contents to the Library and not to the Documents.